# How to activate spell checking for Stack Exchange sites with Firefox on Windows 11

Tags: firefox, windows-11, spell-check

Recently, Firefox does not offer me spell checking when I write questions on Stack exchange sites (e.g., right now typing this question full of typos: dsgdsg jdtjstg). I used to have this problem only for the title (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289695/why-doesnt-the-spell-checker-work-in-question-titles-in-firefox) but now I am also facing this problem for the main multi-line text.

Also, right-click does not offer me the option to activate spell checking.

Mozilla Firefox 119.0.1 (64-Bit)
Windows 11

P.S. In `Settings > General > Language > Check your spelling as you type` I have activated spell checking.

The detailed settings of my Firefox in this regard are:
[image]

PPS: The same bug actually also occours on other web-pages too. I think I don't have firefox spell-checking on any web-page. I do have spell-checking on Overlaf, but I think this is the built in spell-checker by the Overleaf-web-page and not the one by Firefox.

Comment: What is `layout.spellcheckDefault` set to in `about:config`?

Comment: Have you checked that spell checking is on in Settings? **Settings** > **General** > **Language** > **Check your spelling as you type**.

Comment: In both *Settings* and in *About:config* enter "spell" in the *Search* box to view other related settings, too, such as dictionary, or number of errors to allow before checking ceases.

Comment: @DKenn This Box is checked (activated).

Comment: @DavidPostill it is set to 1 (I have added a picture to my question)

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 115.4 esr

Answer (score 0):

I'm still experiencing the same bug in 123.0 (64-Bit) for Windows 11, but a good workaround for me is installing Grammarly. The Firefox (Widnows) built-in spell checker still does not work, but now I can use the Grammarly spell checker for English texts (which is much slower but more advanced).

PS: For Firefox for Linux I don't experience any problem with the built-in spell checker.